# Finitely-generated submodules of a finitely generated module over a PID have a complement?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I found this result about modules:

> Let $R$ be a Principal Ideal Domain and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $C \subseteq M$ be a cyclic submodule of order $\mu$ such that $\mu \in \text{Ann}(M)$. Then, there is a finitely generated submodule $L \subseteq M$ such that $M = C \oplus L$.

I wonder if this is true for any $C \subseteq M$ finitely generated submodule. That is, suppose that $C = \langle x_1, \ldots, x_k \rangle$ and $\langle x_i \rangle \subseteq M$ has order $\mu_i$ such that $\mu_i \in \text{Ann}(M)$ for each $i$. Is it true that there is a finitely generated submodule $L \subseteq M$ such that $M = C \oplus L$?

Comment: The quoted result doesn't look right. Consider $R = M = \mathbb{Z}$, and $C = 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Are you claiming that $2 \mathbb{Z} \cap 3 \mathbb{Z} = \{ 0 \}$? You need that for a sum to be direct.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti you are right, it needs $C$ to have order $\mu$ such that $\mu \in \text{Ann}(M)$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I updated my question.

Comment: @DarioAntolini Can you point me to the proof of the fact : cyclic submodule having a direct sum compliment that you mentioned (the result you found) ? I see that it is clear for $R = \mathbb{Z}$-module as $Ann_x(M)  = \{r \in R: rx = 0\}= (\mu) = Ann(M)$ and the compliment is just all but last term picked directly from fundamental theorm of modules over PID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$The answer to your rephrased question is no.

Consider $R = \mathbb{Z}$, so that $R$-modules are just abelian groups.

Let $M = \Span{a} \oplus \Span{b}$, where $a$ and $b$ have order $4$. Consider the submodule $C = \Span{a, a + 2 b}$. It satisfies your assumption, but it does not have a complement, as

- $C = \Span{a, 2 b}$;
- $M/C$ has order $2$;
- $C$ contains the set $\Set{2a, 2b, 2a + 2 b}$ of the elements of $M$ of order $2$.

You may want to check [pure submodules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_submodule).